# Data manipulation to nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, data-science

I have some data that looks like this:

```
this_data = [{
    "Name": "Bluefox",
    "Sub Name": "Moonglow",
    "Time Series": "{'2022-07-06': 9.5, '2022-07-07': 7.2, '2022-07-08': 10.3}",
    "Probability": "{'2022-07-06': 0.2, '2022-07-07': 0.3, '2022-07-08': 0.5}",
    "Max Value": 466888785.24275005,
},{
    "Name": "Blackbird",
    "Sub Name": "Skylight",
    "Time Series": "{'2022-07-06': -16240599.020647092, '2022-07-07': -17984033.390385196}",
    "Probability": "{'2022-07-06': 0.6, '2022-07-07': 0.7}",
    "Max Value": 81509865.34667145,
},{
    "Name": "Bluefox",
    "Sub Name": "Skylight",
    "Time Series": "{'2022-07-06': -123000, '2022-07-07': -245100}",
    "Probability": "{'2022-07-06': 0.0, '2022-07-07': 0.0}",
    "Max Value": 90409417.34667145,
}]
```

And I want to transform this into:

```
{'Bluefox': {
    'Moonglow': {
        'date': {
            '2022-07-06': {
                'Time Series' : 9.5,
                'Probability' : 0.2,
                
            },
            '2022-07-07' : {
                'Time Series' : 7.2,
                'Probability' : 0.3,

            },
            '2022-07-08' : {
                'Time Series' : 10.3,
                'Probability' : 0.5,

            }
        },
        'Max Value' : 466888785.24275005
    },
    'Skylight':{
        'date': {}
        }
    }
},
{'Blackbird': {
    'Moonglow': {
        'date': {
            '2022-07-06': {
                'Time Series' : 9.5,
                'Probability' : 0.2,
                }
            },
        'Max Value' : 466888785.24275005
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying something like this:

```
import json
import ast
from collections import defaultdict

entity_to_cp = {
    'Bluefox' : ['Moonglow', 'Skylight'],
    'Blackbird' : ['Skylight']
}


inner = defaultdict(list)
between = defaultdict(dict)
between2 = defaultdict(dict)
outer = defaultdict(dict)
for each_dict in this_data:
    for label, all_values in each_dict.items():
        if label == "Name":
            outer[all_values] = between
            cur_e = all_values
        if label == "Sub Name":
            between[all_values] = between2
            cur_cp = all_values
        
        try:
            if cur_cp in entity_to_cp[cur_e]:
                try:
                    all_values = ast.literal_eval(all_values)
                    for k,v in all_values.items():
                        print(k)
                        between2[k] = inner
                        inner[label].append(v)
                    # inner[label].append(all_values)
                except AttributeError as e:
                    print(e)
                except SyntaxError as e:
                    print(e)
                except ValueError as e:
                    print(e)
        except NameError as e:
            print(e)
```

But this doesn't work and I get duplicated values all over the place. Help!

Comment: Your "expected" correct output doesn't look at all correct, if it's a transformation of the input you posted. Did you fill in the ['BlueFox']['Moonglow'] section and kinda skip the others because it was too much?

Comment: I skipped Max Value. And am currently just trying to get the `date` and `time series` /`probability` correct, but my values keep duplicating. If I knew what to do, I'd not turn to SO after wrecking my brain for days. Maybe can tell me how I can stop the duplication? The problem is multiple `Name` can have the same `Sub Name`, and so it duplicates the values. Help/guidance needed, not criticism.

Comment: I'm looking. There's a bunch of errors. I probably would have just looped through it and built result[item["Name"]][item["Sub Name"]] = report(item) and parse the date-data for each item separately.

Comment: What's the "between" stuff for? I thought you just wanted to transform where stuff is, but not actually change anything or compute new values. It seems like you are storing data from different items when you really want to forget everything from the previous entry and just process entirely new data for each new item.

Comment: I am not too familiar with pandas and data science, was trying to resolve through dict's instead but was a failed attempt. The answer below is precisely what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to export "Name" and "Sub Name" on different levels but you can do it by looping over your dataframes grouped by "Name" (using pandas). There are additional difficulties like converting your strings to dictionaries and switching the levels of the dates and "Time Series"/"Probability" keys:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import ast

this_data = [{
    "Name": "Bluefox",
    "Sub Name": "Moonglow",
    "Time Series": "{'2022-07-06': 9.5, '2022-07-07': 7.2, '2022-07-08': 10.3}",
    "Probability": "{'2022-07-06': 0.2, '2022-07-07': 0.3, '2022-07-08': 0.5}",
    "Max Value": 466888785.24275005,
},{
    "Name": "Blackbird",
    "Sub Name": "Skylight",
    "Time Series": "{'2022-07-06': -16240599.020647092, '2022-07-07': -17984033.390385196}",
    "Probability": "{'2022-07-06': 0.6, '2022-07-07': 0.7}",
    "Max Value": 81509865.34667145,
},{
    "Name": "Bluefox",
    "Sub Name": "Skylight",
    "Time Series": "{'2022-07-06': -123000, '2022-07-07': -245100}",
    "Probability": "{'2022-07-06': 0.0, '2022-07-07': 0.0}",
    "Max Value": 90409417.34667145,
}]

df = pd.DataFrame(this_data)
record = []
for name, sub_df in df.groupby('Name'):
    sub_df.set_index('Sub Name', inplace=True)
    # converting your strings to dict:
    sub_df[['Time Series', 'Probability']] = sub_df[['Time Series', 'Probability']].applymap(ast.literal_eval)
    # switching key levels:
    sub_df['date'] = [pd.DataFrame(dic).to_dict(orient="index")
                     for dic in sub_df[['Time Series', 'Probability']].to_dict(orient="records")]
    sub_df.drop(['Name', 'Time Series', 'Probability'], axis=1, inplace=True)
    record.append({name: sub_df.to_dict(orient="index")})

print(json.dumps(record, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "Blackbird": {
            "Skylight": {
                "Max Value": 81509865.34667145,
                "date": {
                    "2022-07-06": {
                        "Time Series": -16240599.020647092,
                        "Probability": 0.6
                    },
                    "2022-07-07": {
                        "Time Series": -17984033.390385196,
                        "Probability": 0.7
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Bluefox": {
            "Moonglow": {
                "Max Value": 466888785.24275005,
                "date": {
                    "2022-07-06": {
                        "Time Series": 9.5,
                        "Probability": 0.2
                    },
                    "2022-07-07": {
                        "Time Series": 7.2,
                        "Probability": 0.3
                    },
                    "2022-07-08": {
                        "Time Series": 10.3,
                        "Probability": 0.5
                    }
                }
            },
            "Skylight": {
                "Max Value": 90409417.34667145,
                "date": {
                    "2022-07-06": {
                        "Time Series": -123000,
                        "Probability": 0.0
                    },
                    "2022-07-07": {
                        "Time Series": -245100,
                        "Probability": 0.0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: what if I want this to output a `df` over a `dict`? I tried doing `main_df = pd.DataFrame()` and `main_df.append(sub_df)` but that didn't like it very much.

Comment: You can use `concat`